# How to use the Search Bar to search through Multiple Views? (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, searchbar

iOS, Swift

What the App Does Now:

The main view of this app contains categories (arranged in a table view), when clicking those categories, the app brings the user to a scrolling view with basic text, and images. The main view also contains a search bar. The user is able to enter a category name, and filter the results.

What the App Needs to Do:

I want to better the search bar, and filtered results. I want the user to have the ability of filtering category names not only by entering the name of the category, but also by entering text that is contained within a specific scrolling view.

Ex: The category names are: "Letters", and "Numbers". When the user clicks "Letters", they are brought to a view that says "A B C D .. Z", when "Numbers" is clicked, they are brought to the view that says "1 2 3 4 .. 10". If the user enters "A B" into the search bar, the main view filters to show only the "Letters" category. If the user enters "3" into the search bar, the main view filters to show only the "Numbers" category.

In Conclusion:

I'm still fairly new to app development, and this has me stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated, whether code, or a reference.

Thank You.

**TableViewController**

Variables:

```
@IBOutlet var searchForTool: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var toolTable: UITableView!

var searchActive : Bool = false
var filtered : [String] = []
var data = ["  Make", "  Model"]
var identities = ["A", "B"]
```

Search Bar filter:

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = data.filter({ (text: String) -> Bool in

        return text.range(of: searchText, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive) != nil
    })

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false
    } else {
        searchActive = true
    }
    self.toolTable.reloadData()
}
```

Displayed Cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    if(searchActive){
        cell.toolLabel.text = filtered[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        cell.toolLabel.text = data[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}
```

Will display more code if needed.

Comment: Adding code and screenshots would help

Comment: Alright I'll add some code from the TableViewController

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues here:

- **how is your data structured?**

as a solution to this I would go for something like this:

```
class Item {
    var name: String!
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Category {
    var items = [Item]()
    var name: String!

    init(items: [Item], name: String) {
        self.items = items
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
let letterItems = [Item(name: "A"), Item(name: "B"), Item(name: "C")]
let lettersCategory = Category(items: letterItems, name: "Letters")

let numberItems = [Item(name: "1"), Item(name: "2"), Item(name: "3")]
let numbersCategory = Category(items: numberItems, name: "Numbers")

let cat: [Category] = [lettersCategory, numbersCategory]
```

- **How is your search defined?**

Here you could have multiple options:

1. search text needs to be found as it is written in any of category.name or item.name: the "A B" won't be found in this case in any of item.name. If the search is "A" -> "Letters" is a match

   ```
   let searchItem = "A"

   let result = cat.filter({ $0.name.range(of: searchItem) != nil || $0.items.filter({$0.name.range(of: searchItem) != nil }).count > 0})
   ```
2. an "or" search, like google does:

   - first separate search string by " "
   - take every element and use the same method like above -
   - flatten result
   - add to a `results` variable
   - continue with the next word

Comment: Thank you for the response, and sorry for not providing my code structure earlier (I have now). As you can see, our structure differs. But I will further examine your code, it might bring me closer to the solution.

Comment: You need to link you entities: `data` with `identities` so that you can do a cascading filter.

Comment: How would I go about doing that. From the bits that I read it sounds fairly complicated. With Biquadratic Filter Functions, vDSP API, etc.